# Wsus client getting error 403 (0x80244018)

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, iis, windows-server-2016, wsus

It's a couple of days that my clients can't download updates from my wsus server.
They control and find updates normally but when it comes to download them, they are all getting 403 error from the server.
Here the log file entry:

```
2023/03/20 08:55:33.7366979 12264 1424  DownloadManager DO job {FB5BA17F-944D-4569-84F0-58FF9E125F57} failed, updateId = 93C74394-F400-4CF4-B49D-B750156013E0.201, hr = 0x80190193. File URL = https://xxxxxx:8531/, local path = C:\windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\ae4be6f6193482f51b7b4289ad4c2931\34acd51e6ca1c835eacff757d6ea75c4a22ad3cb, The response headers = HTTP/1.1 403   Date: Mon, 20 Mar 2023 07:55:31 GMT  Content-Length: 1233  Content-Type: text/html  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0  x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

I already tried  to reset wsus  but nothing changed.
Google not helped me neither.

Comment: Do you get an error when you navigate to `http://SERVER-IP:8530/selfupdate/UPDATE-FILE.cab` from the client device?

Comment: The `http://ip:8530/selfupdate/iuident.cab` file is downloaded correctly

Comment: Access denied could be a matter of permissions. See [Verifying WSUS Server Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc708545(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: "The http://ip:8530/selfupdate/iuident.cab file is downloaded correctly" - Windows is using `https://xxxxxx:8531/selfupdate/iuident.cab` not `http://xxxxxx:8531/selfupdate/iuident.cab`

Comment: In https also the file is downloaded. I also just tried to reset wsus another time but deleting also the iis website but the behavior is the same for all clients: searching correctly, error downloading, reporting correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what it was, but I installed the update manually on the clients and the issue is gone.
UPDATE:
The update installed was the march 2023 cumulative update ([KB5023773](https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/topic/21-marzo-2023-kb5023773-build-del-sistema-operativo-19042-2788-19044-2788-e-19045-2788-preview-5850ac11-dd43-4550-89ec-9e63353fef23))

Comment: Which update did you install exactly?  You should [edit] your answer to provide enough information so it can be helpful to anyone with the same problem as you.